# Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTPS v1 python

Tags: python, firebase-cloud-messaging, micropython

I am currently looking at using a micropython script to send a notification over FCM when a certain event happens but I am struggling to understand the documentation and cannot find any examples online of python or micropython. I have requests and all the rest set up perfectly however it's just the FCM stuff I'm confused with.

If anyone could redirect me to an example of the http request I would need to send as well as the method of authentication that would be greatly appreciated!